# Monitoring Multiple ElasticSearch Instances through DataDog

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, datadog

[DataDog offers monitoring of ElasticSearch clusters](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/elastic), which are configurable through the elastic.d/conf.yaml file. There is a `instances` property which identifies the cluster url, among other settings. Is it possible to update the YAML file to include multiple clusters? It does not appear the -url property takes an array, and ideally monitoring would be configurable per cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Within the config file, users can add multiple instances under the instance property. Each new URL must have a `-` and all following properties will apply to the above url. For example

```
instances: 
   - url: https://path.toelasticsearchinstance.com
     cluster_stats: true
   - url: https://path.toanotherelasticsearchinstance.com
     cluster_stats: false
```